# How to find Bitcoin wallet address

Tags: wallet

I'm trying to find the address for Bitcoin wallet so someone can transfer me Bitcoin because my data got stolen so I'm getting compensated for it

Comment: This sounds like you're being scammed. Can you provide more details? Which wallet are you using? Who is compensating you and why?

Comment: Control and compensation department representative I'm being compensated because someone scammed my data

Comment: You are almost certainly being scammed. What is the name of the business that has the "control and compensation department"? did you first learn about it by a direct message from them? if so, definitely a scam. Remember - no genuine business will ever ask you to pay fees to release money. Don't believe lies about COT codes, minimum balances, wallet validation etc etc - all lies.